# How to bind multiple labels using leaflet.label?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-label

I am using Leaflet and it works well. I am using leaflet.label as well and that works nicely as well. The problem is that I would like to display two labels to the right of the marker. If I call `bindLabel` twice, then the second overrides the first. How could I make sure that I have two labels, both to the right of the marker and the second label is above the first one?

This is how I tried:

```
newMarker.bindLabel(result, { noHide: true }).bindLabel("secondlabel", { noHide: true });
```

Thanks

EDIT:

I have managed to display the texts using a single call to `bindLabel`, like this:

```
newMarker.bindLabel(result + "<br>secondLabel", { noHide: true });
```

but this seems to be a too hacky solution.
[Here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label/issues/80) they say it is not possible, but that was written in 2014. It might be possible since then.

Comment: Personally I see nothing wrong in using HTML code (including the `<br>` tag for a line break) in the label's content to provide more information… As for multiple labels, I think there is still nothing out-of-the-box.

Comment: @ghybs, thanks for the comment. If we do not have the possibility to bind multiple labels, then it will be impossible to draw one to the left and one to the right. I know that is not my current desire, but the lack of that possibility is not too good. Maybe it is worth to look into the code of the plugin and see how bindLabel works and make that plural. I know it is a hack, but if it is an elegant code, they might add it to future releases.

Comment: Indeed it could be interesting to have like a "group" option so that each label can be attached to a group with a particular position for example. Now this plugin is Open Source, which means "they" would be more than happy to receive Pull Requests! :-)

Comment: @ghybs, that's right. Let me sort out the current problem and then see what I can do. It is very possible that I will modify the functionality and push it. Unless they say "don't push it", off course :) Stay tuned

Comment: @ghybs, I have answered my question, thanks for advices and useful comments.

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to solve it. I am lazy to push it to their repo right now, but I will probably do it in the future. The logic of the solution is as follows:

- `this.label` -> `this.labels`
- `this.labels` is an array of `LeafletLabel`s
- apply the change for methods containing `this.label`
- move `this._labelNoHide` = `options.noHide` into the `if` to prevent bugs

The labels will act similarly for the subset of `options` which is handled singularly / marker. Sorry, folks, singularizing `noHide` or `opacity` to label level instead of marker level is beyond the scope of this question. I might resolve those later though.

The code is as follows:

```
/*
    Leaflet.label, a plugin that adds labels to markers and vectors for Leaflet powered maps.
    (c) 2012-2013, Jacob Toye, Smartrak

    https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label
    http://leafletjs.com
    https://github.com/jacobtoye
*/
(function (factory, window) {

    // define an AMD module that relies on 'leaflet'
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['leaflet'], factory);

        // define a Common JS module that relies on 'leaflet'
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory(require('leaflet'));
    }

    // attach your plugin to the global 'L' variable
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.L) {
        window.LeafletLabel = factory(L);
    }
}(function (L) {
    L.labelVersion = '0.2.4';


    var LeafletLabel = L.Class.extend({

        includes: L.Mixin.Events,

        options: {
            className: '',
            clickable: false,
            direction: 'right',
            noHide: false,
            offset: [12, -15], // 6 (width of the label triangle) + 6 (padding)
            opacity: 1,
            zoomAnimation: true
        },

        initialize: function (options, source) {
            L.setOptions(this, options);

            this._source = source;
            this._animated = L.Browser.any3d && this.options.zoomAnimation;
            this._isOpen = false;
        },

        onAdd: function (map) {
            this._map = map;

            this._pane = this.options.pane ? map._panes[this.options.pane] :
                this._source instanceof L.Marker ? map._panes.markerPane : map._panes.popupPane;

            if (!this._container) {
                this._initLayout();
            }

            this._pane.appendChild(this._container);

            this._initInteraction();

            this._update();

            this.setOpacity(this.options.opacity);

            map
                .on('moveend', this._onMoveEnd, this)
                .on('viewreset', this._onViewReset, this);

            if (this._animated) {
                map.on('zoomanim', this._zoomAnimation, this);
            }

            if (L.Browser.touch && !this.options.noHide) {
                L.DomEvent.on(this._container, 'click', this.close, this);
                map.on('click', this.close, this);
            }
        },

        onRemove: function (map) {
            this._pane.removeChild(this._container);

            map.off({
                zoomanim: this._zoomAnimation,
                moveend: this._onMoveEnd,
                viewreset: this._onViewReset
            }, this);

            this._removeInteraction();

            this._map = null;
        },

        setLatLng: function (latlng) {
            this._latlng = L.latLng(latlng);
            if (this._map) {
                this._updatePosition();
            }
            return this;
        },

        setContent: function (content) {
            // Backup previous content and store new content
            this._previousContent = this._content;
            this._content = content;

            this._updateContent();

            return this;
        },

        close: function () {
            var map = this._map;

            if (map) {
                if (L.Browser.touch && !this.options.noHide) {
                    L.DomEvent.off(this._container, 'click', this.close);
                    map.off('click', this.close, this);
                }

                map.removeLayer(this);
            }
        },

        updateZIndex: function (zIndex) {
            this._zIndex = zIndex;

            if (this._container && this._zIndex) {
                this._container.style.zIndex = zIndex;
            }
        },

        setOpacity: function (opacity) {
            this.options.opacity = opacity;

            if (this._container) {
                L.DomUtil.setOpacity(this._container, opacity);
            }
        },

        _initLayout: function () {
            this._container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-label ' + this.options.className + ' leaflet-zoom-animated');
            this.updateZIndex(this._zIndex);
        },

        _update: function () {
            if (!this._map) { return; }

            this._container.style.visibility = 'hidden';

            this._updateContent();
            this._updatePosition();

            this._container.style.visibility = '';
        },

        _updateContent: function () {
            if (!this._content || !this._map || this._prevContent === this._content) {
                return;
            }

            if (typeof this._content === 'string') {
                this._container.innerHTML = this._content;

                this._prevContent = this._content;

                this._labelWidth = this._container.offsetWidth;
            }
        },

        _updatePosition: function () {
            var pos = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._latlng);

            this._setPosition(pos);
        },

        _setPosition: function (pos) {
            var map = this._map,
                container = this._container,
                centerPoint = map.latLngToContainerPoint(map.getCenter()),
                labelPoint = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(pos),
                direction = this.options.direction,
                labelWidth = this._labelWidth,
                offset = L.point(this.options.offset);

            // position to the right (right or auto & needs to)
            if (direction === 'right' || direction === 'auto' && labelPoint.x < centerPoint.x) {
                L.DomUtil.addClass(container, 'leaflet-label-right');
                L.DomUtil.removeClass(container, 'leaflet-label-left');

                pos = pos.add(offset);
            } else { // position to the left
                L.DomUtil.addClass(container, 'leaflet-label-left');
                L.DomUtil.removeClass(container, 'leaflet-label-right');

                pos = pos.add(L.point(-offset.x - labelWidth, offset.y));
            }

            L.DomUtil.setPosition(container, pos);
        },

        _zoomAnimation: function (opt) {
            var pos = this._map._latLngToNewLayerPoint(this._latlng, opt.zoom, opt.center).round();

            this._setPosition(pos);
        },

        _onMoveEnd: function () {
            if (!this._animated || this.options.direction === 'auto') {
                this._updatePosition();
            }
        },

        _onViewReset: function (e) {
            /* if map resets hard, we must update the label */
            if (e && e.hard) {
                this._update();
            }
        },

        _initInteraction: function () {
            if (!this.options.clickable) { return; }

            var container = this._container,
                events = ['dblclick', 'mousedown', 'mouseover', 'mouseout', 'contextmenu'];

            L.DomUtil.addClass(container, 'leaflet-clickable');
            L.DomEvent.on(container, 'click', this._onMouseClick, this);

            for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                L.DomEvent.on(container, events[i], this._fireMouseEvent, this);
            }
        },

        _removeInteraction: function () {
            if (!this.options.clickable) { return; }

            var container = this._container,
                events = ['dblclick', 'mousedown', 'mouseover', 'mouseout', 'contextmenu'];

            L.DomUtil.removeClass(container, 'leaflet-clickable');
            L.DomEvent.off(container, 'click', this._onMouseClick, this);

            for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                L.DomEvent.off(container, events[i], this._fireMouseEvent, this);
            }
        },

        _onMouseClick: function (e) {
            if (this.hasEventListeners(e.type)) {
                L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
            }

            this.fire(e.type, {
                originalEvent: e
            });
        },

        _fireMouseEvent: function (e) {
            this.fire(e.type, {
                originalEvent: e
            });

            // TODO proper custom event propagation
            // this line will always be called if marker is in a FeatureGroup
            if (e.type === 'contextmenu' && this.hasEventListeners(e.type)) {
                L.DomEvent.preventDefault(e);
            }
            if (e.type !== 'mousedown') {
                L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
            } else {
                L.DomEvent.preventDefault(e);
            }
        }
    });


    /*global LeafletLabel */

    // This object is a mixin for L.Marker and L.CircleMarker. We declare it here as both need to include the contents.
    L.BaseMarkerMethods = {
        showLabel: function () {
            if (this.labels && this._map) {
                for (var labelIndex in this.labels) {
                    this.labels[labelIndex].setLatLng(this._latlng);
                    this._map.showLabel(this.labels[labelIndex]);
                }
            }

            return this;
        },

        hideLabel: function () {
            if (this.labels) {
                for (var labelIndex in this.labels) {
                    this.labels[labelIndex].close();
                }
            }
            return this;
        },

        setLabelNoHide: function (noHide) {
            if (this._labelNoHide === noHide) {
                return;
            }

            this._labelNoHide = noHide;

            if (noHide) {
                this._removeLabelRevealHandlers();
                this.showLabel();
            } else {
                this._addLabelRevealHandlers();
                this.hideLabel();
            }
        },

        bindLabel: function (content, options) {
            var labelAnchor = this.options.icon ? this.options.icon.options.labelAnchor : this.options.labelAnchor,
                anchor = L.point(labelAnchor) || L.point(0, 0);

            anchor = anchor.add(LeafletLabel.prototype.options.offset);

            if (options && options.offset) {
                anchor = anchor.add(options.offset);
            }

            options = L.Util.extend({ offset: anchor }, options);

            if (!this.labels) {
                this._labelNoHide = options.noHide;
                this.labels = [];
                if (!this._labelNoHide) {
                    this._addLabelRevealHandlers();
                }

                this
                    .on('remove', this.hideLabel, this)
                    .on('move', this._moveLabel, this)
                    .on('add', this._onMarkerAdd, this);

                this._hasLabelHandlers = true;
            }

            this.labels.push(new LeafletLabel(options, this).setContent(content));

            return this;
        },

        unbindLabel: function () {
            if (this.labels) {
                this.hideLabel();

                this.labels = null;

                if (this._hasLabelHandlers) {
                    if (!this._labelNoHide) {
                        this._removeLabelRevealHandlers();
                    }

                    this
                        .off('remove', this.hideLabel, this)
                        .off('move', this._moveLabel, this)
                        .off('add', this._onMarkerAdd, this);
                }

                this._hasLabelHandlers = false;
            }
            return this;
        },

        updateLabelContent: function (content, index) {
            if ((this.labels) && (index < this.labels.length)) {
                this.labels[index].setContent(content);
            }
        },

        getLabels: function () {
            return this.labels;
        },

        _onMarkerAdd: function () {
            if (this._labelNoHide) {
                this.showLabel();
            }
        },

        _addLabelRevealHandlers: function () {
            this
                .on('mouseover', this.showLabel, this)
                .on('mouseout', this.hideLabel, this);

            if (L.Browser.touch) {
                this.on('click', this.showLabel, this);
            }
        },

        _removeLabelRevealHandlers: function () {
            this
                .off('mouseover', this.showLabel, this)
                .off('mouseout', this.hideLabel, this);

            if (L.Browser.touch) {
                this.off('click', this.showLabel, this);
            }
        },

        _moveLabel: function (e) {
            this.label.setLatLng(e.latlng);
        }
    };


    // Add in an option to icon that is used to set where the label anchor is
    L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
        labelAnchor: new L.Point(9, -20)
    });

    // Have to do this since Leaflet is loaded before this plugin and initializes
    // L.Marker.options.icon therefore missing our mixin above.
    L.Marker.mergeOptions({
        icon: new L.Icon.Default()
    });

    L.Marker.include(L.BaseMarkerMethods);
    L.Marker.include({
        _originalUpdateZIndex: L.Marker.prototype._updateZIndex,

        _updateZIndex: function (offset) {
            var zIndex = this._zIndex + offset;

            this._originalUpdateZIndex(offset);

            if (this.labels) {
                for (var labelIndex in this.labels) {
                    this.labels[labelIndex].updateZIndex(zIndex);
                }
            }
        },

        _originalSetOpacity: L.Marker.prototype.setOpacity,

        setOpacity: function (opacity, labelHasSemiTransparency) {
            this.options.labelHasSemiTransparency = labelHasSemiTransparency;

            this._originalSetOpacity(opacity);
        },

        _originalUpdateOpacity: L.Marker.prototype._updateOpacity,

        _updateOpacity: function () {
            var absoluteOpacity = this.options.opacity === 0 ? 0 : 1;

            this._originalUpdateOpacity();

            if (this.labels) {
                for (var labelIndex in labels) {
                    this.labels[labelIndex].setOpacity(this.options.labelHasSemiTransparency ? this.options.opacity : absoluteOpacity);
                }
            }
        },

        _originalSetLatLng: L.Marker.prototype.setLatLng,

        setLatLng: function (latlng) {
            if (this.labels && !this._labelNoHide) {
                this.hideLabel();
            }

            return this._originalSetLatLng(latlng);
        }
    });

    // Add in an option to icon that is used to set where the label anchor is
    L.CircleMarker.mergeOptions({
        labelAnchor: new L.Point(0, 0)
    });


    L.CircleMarker.include(L.BaseMarkerMethods);

    /*global LeafletLabel */

    L.Path.include({
        bindLabel: function (content, options) {
            if (!this.label || this.label.options !== options) {
                this.label = new LeafletLabel(options, this);
            }

            this.label.setContent(content);

            if (!this._showLabelAdded) {
                this
                    .on('mouseover', this._showLabel, this)
                    .on('mousemove', this._moveLabel, this)
                    .on('mouseout remove', this._hideLabel, this);

                if (L.Browser.touch) {
                    this.on('click', this._showLabel, this);
                }
                this._showLabelAdded = true;
            }

            return this;
        },

        unbindLabel: function () {
            if (this.label) {
                this._hideLabel();
                this.label = null;
                this._showLabelAdded = false;
                this
                    .off('mouseover', this._showLabel, this)
                    .off('mousemove', this._moveLabel, this)
                    .off('mouseout remove', this._hideLabel, this);
            }
            return this;
        },

        updateLabelContent: function (content) {
            if (this.label) {
                this.label.setContent(content);
            }
        },

        _showLabel: function (e) {
            this.label.setLatLng(e.latlng);
            this._map.showLabel(this.label);
        },

        _moveLabel: function (e) {
            this.label.setLatLng(e.latlng);
        },

        _hideLabel: function () {
            this.label.close();
        }
    });


    L.Map.include({
        showLabel: function (label) {
            return this.addLayer(label);
        }
    });

    L.FeatureGroup.include({
        // TODO: remove this when AOP is supported in Leaflet, need this as we cannot put code in removeLayer()
        clearLayers: function () {
            this.unbindLabel();
            this.eachLayer(this.removeLayer, this);
            return this;
        },

        bindLabel: function (content, options) {
            return this.invoke('bindLabel', content, options);
        },

        unbindLabel: function () {
            return this.invoke('unbindLabel');
        },

        updateLabelContent: function (content) {
            this.invoke('updateLabelContent', content);
        }
    });

    return LeafletLabel;
}, window));
```